# JRuby loadpath messed up

Tags: jar, websphere, jruby, load-path

I am embedding JRuby on a JAR file and it's being used by a EAR file that I am deploying to WebSphere. When I call the class from my workspace, it works fine, however when I call it inside WebSphere, here's what I get:

```
[3/31/11 11:21:15:984 BRT] 00000042 SystemErr     R classpath:/lib/xmlcompare.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from classpath:/lib/xmlcompare.rb:4
    from classpath:/lib/xmlcompare.rb:1:in `require'
    from <script>:1
```

After some research, I noticed that when I run the code in the JAR file from the command line, the loadpath looks like this:

```
lib
lib/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib
lib/gems/rainbow-1.1.1/lib
lib/gems/syntax-1.0.0/lib
lib/gems/xml-simple-1.0.14/lib
file:/C:/RSA/workspace/sdops-XmlCompare/pkg/XmlCompare.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
file:/C:/RSA/workspace/sdops-XmlCompare/pkg/XmlCompare.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
file:/C:/RSA/workspace/sdops-XmlCompare/pkg/XmlCompare.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8
.
```

However, after the JAR is deployed to WebSphere (bundled with an EAR), here's how the loadpath looks:

```
lib
lib/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib
lib/gems/rainbow-1.1.1/lib
lib/gems/syntax-1.0.0/lib
lib/gems/xml-simple-1.0.14/lib
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/1.8
.
```

I have tried adding a few more entries to the loadpath:

Making it:

```
lib
lib/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib
lib/gems/rainbow-1.1.1/lib
lib/gems/syntax-1.0.0/lib
lib/gems/xml-simple-1.0.14/lib
META-INF/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
META-INF/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
META-INF/lib/ruby/1.8
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
C:/WINDOWS/TEMP//lib/ruby/1.8
.
```

But that didn't make any change.

Do you have any clue why the loadpath gets corrupted when running inside WebSphere and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to $LOAD_PATH:

```
META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8
```