# JRuby 1.6.7 Weblogic 10.3 LoadError: no such file to load -- active_record

Tags: rubygems, weblogic, jruby

My goal:  To have all Ruby source code and gems in jar files that are packaged with the war/ear.  This is required because the organization I work for will not accept them being placed on the file system outside the J2EE container.

Using JRuby 1.6.7 on Weblogic 10.3  I am getting the following error.  "LoadError: no such file to load -- active_record".  My setup is that I have downloaded jruby-complete and am placing it in my web application. I also added ActiveRecord and its supporting gems to jruby-gems.jar using [These directions](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar).  When I build my web application I added both jars to the war file lib and to the META-INF/lib in the ear file.  I also tried adding them to the APP-INF/lib folder of the ear file.  Still receiving LoadError.

Additionally I added the following to my loadpath as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501455/jruby-loadpath-messed-up).  I have done this with and without the beginning forward slash and with and withouth the "classpath:"

```
    List paths = new ArrayList();
    paths.add("classpath:/ruby");
    paths.add("classpath:/myapp");
    paths.add("classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/soart");
    paths.add("classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9");
    paths.add("classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9");
    paths.add("classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared");
    paths.add("classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/1.9");
    container.setLoadPaths(paths);
```

All of my unit tests are passing and I have verified that the jar files are making it into the ear and war files.  The unit tests cover using ActiveRecord to pull data from the database.

Because I won't control my deployment server I set my GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME environment variables to be an empty string.  All the resources need to come from within the war/ear.

Also its worth mentioning that this is not a Ruby on Rails application nor can I make it one at this time.

**Update**

Tried placing the gem files in jruby-complete.jar without success.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the Active Record libraries. If you are able to, try installing them via

```
sudo gem install activerecord
```